# Merging Arrays Assignment in Java

Tags: java, arrays, merge, variable-assignment

**In this lab, you will be creating a program that merges two arrays of non-negative (equal to or greater than 0) integers. Your program will accept each array as input from the keyboard. You do not know ahead of time how many values will be entered, but you can assume each array will have a maximum length of 10,000 elements. To stop entering values enter a negative number. You may disregard any negative numbers input and not store these in the array.
The elements of the two input arrays should be in increasing order. In other words, each array element must have a value that is greater than or equal to the previous element value. An array may contain repeated elements.
After the two arrays have been input, your program must check to make sure the elements of each array have been entered in order. If an out of order element is found, print the message “ERROR: Array not in correct order”.
Your task is to merge the two input arrays into a new array, with all elements in order, lowest to highest. Print out each of the original arrays entered, followed by the merged array.
Please note that your program must output the arrays with exactly one space between each of the numbers.**

My issue comes towards the end of my code.  For some reason it doesn't merge more complex arrays in the correct order.  It works for arrays like {1, 3, 5} and {2, 4, 6} --> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}, but not others.  I calculated it by hand and I found it should come out correct.  Can anyone see my error and how to fix it?

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        int one[]= new int[10000];  //Original array with specified index
        int two[]= new int[10000];  //Original array with specified index

        int lengthShort=0;          //initializes the length of the shorter of the two arrays
                                    //either mergeOne or mergeTwo

        int lengthLong=0;           //initializes the length of the longer of the two arrays
                                    //either mergeOne or mergeTwo



        int a =0;                   //Initialize the count variable for array one
        int b =0;                   //Initialize the count variable for array two
    //STEP A
        System.out.println("Enter the values for the first array, "
                + "up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");

        //This loop sets up for the creation of a new array for the first array
        //without all the null values.
        for(int i=0; i<one.length; i++){

            one[i] = scan.nextInt();
            a++;
            if(one[i]<0){
                one[i]=0;
                break;
            }
        }
        int length1 = a-1;

        System.out.println("Enter the values for the second array, "
                + "up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");
        //This loop sets up for the creation of a new array for the second array
        //without all the null values.
        for(int i=0; i<two.length; i++){

            two[i] = scan.nextInt();
            b++;
            if(two[i]<0){
                two[i]=0;
                break;
            }

        }

        int lengthTwo = b-1;

    //STEP B
        int mergeOne[] = new int[length1];  //new array initialized without null values

        for (int i = 0; i<mergeOne.length; i++){
            mergeOne[i]=one[i];
        }
        int mergeTwo[] = new int[lengthTwo];    //new array initialized without null values

        for (int i = 0; i<mergeTwo.length; i++){
            mergeTwo[i]=two[i];
        }

        //After new arrays without null values created, I print out the inputed arrays.
        System.out.println("First Array:");

        for(int i=0; i<mergeOne.length; i++){
        System.out.print(mergeOne[i] + " ");
        }

        //After new arrays without null values created, I print out the inputed arrays.
        System.out.println("\nSecond Array:");

        for(int i=0; i<mergeTwo.length; i++){
        System.out.print(mergeTwo[i] + " ");
        }

    //STEP C
        //Because the for loop below runs into the Error out of Bounds statement
        //(merged.length goes beyond the length of either mergeOne or mergeTwo)
        //I'm going to create an integer for the length of the shortest array
        //(Ex. MergeOne<MergeTwo, so tempLength = MergeOne.length).
        //This will fill the merged array part way.  Then I should probably
        //create another for loop starting at tempLength and going to MergeTwo.length
        //to complete the merge array.  Hopefully this works.
        if(mergeOne.length<=mergeTwo.length){
            lengthLong = mergeTwo.length;
            lengthShort = mergeOne.length;
        }

        else if(mergeOne.length>=mergeTwo.length){
            lengthShort = mergeTwo.length;
            lengthLong = mergeOne.length;
        }

        int merged[] = new int[length1 + lengthTwo];


        for(int i = 0; i<lengthShort; i++){
            if(i==0){
                if(mergeOne[i]<=mergeTwo[i]){
                    merged[i] = mergeOne[i];
                    merged[i+1] = mergeTwo[i];
                }
                else if(mergeTwo[i]<=mergeOne[i]){
                    merged[i] = mergeTwo[i];
                    merged[i+1]= mergeOne[i];
                }
            }
            else if(i>0){
                if(mergeOne[i]<=mergeTwo[i]){
                    merged[i+i] = mergeOne[i];
                    merged[i+i+1] = mergeTwo[i];
                }
                else if(mergeTwo[i]<=mergeOne[i]){
                    merged[i+i] = mergeTwo[i];
                    merged[i+i+1]= mergeOne[i];
                }
            }
        }
        //If mergeOne.length equals mergeTwo.length, it skips over next step.
        if(mergeOne.length<mergeTwo.length){
            for(int k=lengthShort; k<lengthLong; k++){
                merged[k]=mergeTwo[k];
            }
        }
        //If mergeOne.length equals mergeTwo.length, it skips over next step.
        if(mergeOne.length>mergeTwo.length){
                for(int k=lengthShort; k<lengthLong; k++){
                    merged[k]=mergeOne[k];
            }
        }

    //STEP D
        //This is supposed to sort the final merged array.
        for(int i = 0; i<merged.length; i++){
            if((i+1)==merged.length)        //Prevents an ErrorOutofBounds message
                break;
            if(merged[i]>merged[i+1]){
                int temp = merged[i+1];
                merged[i+1]=merged[i];
                merged[i]= temp;

            }
        }

        System.out.println("Merged array in order is: ");

        for(int i = 0; i<merged.length; i++){
        System.out.print(merged[i] + " ");
        }
    }
    }

}
```

Comment: *"It works for [...], but not others"*. What others?

Comment: I was using that as an example.  An example of inputed arrays it doesn't work for would be {3, 3, 5, 6, 8, 9} paired with {3, 4, 5, 6}.  I calculated this one by hand and couldn't find a problem, but when I did it on the console, it didn't merge in the correct order.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

//I typed your code in, and I think you just used an extra { at the end.
//When you remove it, it works out just fine. 
//I fixed it here and it works perfectly for me.


public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

    int one[]= new int[10000];  //Original array with specified index
    int two[]= new int[10000];  //Original array with specified index

    int lengthShort=0;          //initializes the length of the shorter of the two arrays
                                //either mergeOne or mergeTwo

    int lengthLong=0;           //initializes the length of the longer of the two arrays
                                //either mergeOne or mergeTwo



    int a =0;                   //Initialize the count variable for array one
    int b =0;                   //Initialize the count variable for array two
//STEP A
    System.out.println("Enter the values for the first array, "
            + "up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");

    //This loop sets up for the creation of a new array for the first array
    //without all the null values.
    for(int i=0; i<one.length; i++){

        one[i] = scan.nextInt();
        a++;
        if(one[i]<0){
            one[i]=0;
            break;
        }
    }
    int length1 = a-1;

    System.out.println("Enter the values for the second array, "
            + "up to 10000 values, enter a negative number to quit");
    //This loop sets up for the creation of a new array for the second array
    //without all the null values.
    for(int i=0; i<two.length; i++){

        two[i] = scan.nextInt();
        b++;
        if(two[i]<0){
            two[i]=0;
            break;
        }

    }

    int lengthTwo = b-1;

//STEP B
    int mergeOne[] = new int[length1];  //new array initialized without null values

    for (int i = 0; i<mergeOne.length; i++){
        mergeOne[i]=one[i];
    }
    int mergeTwo[] = new int[lengthTwo];    //new array initialized without null values

    for (int i = 0; i<mergeTwo.length; i++){
        mergeTwo[i]=two[i];
    }

    //After new arrays without null values created, I print out the inputed arrays.
    System.out.println("First Array:");

    for(int i=0; i<mergeOne.length; i++){
    System.out.print(mergeOne[i] + " ");
    }

    //After new arrays without null values created, I print out the inputed arrays.
    System.out.println("\nSecond Array:");

    for(int i=0; i<mergeTwo.length; i++){
    System.out.print(mergeTwo[i] + " ");
    }

//STEP C
    //Because the for loop below runs into the Error out of Bounds statement
    //(merged.length goes beyond the length of either mergeOne or mergeTwo)
    //I'm going to create an integer for the length of the shortest array
    //(Ex. MergeOne<MergeTwo, so tempLength = MergeOne.length).
    //This will fill the merged array part way.  Then I should probably
    //create another for loop starting at tempLength and going to MergeTwo.length
    //to complete the merge array.  Hopefully this works.
    if(mergeOne.length<=mergeTwo.length){
        lengthLong = mergeTwo.length;
        lengthShort = mergeOne.length;
    }

    else if(mergeOne.length>=mergeTwo.length){
        lengthShort = mergeTwo.length;
        lengthLong = mergeOne.length;
    }

    int merged[] = new int[length1 + lengthTwo];


    for(int i = 0; i<lengthShort; i++){
        if(i==0){
            if(mergeOne[i]<=mergeTwo[i]){
                merged[i] = mergeOne[i];
                merged[i+1] = mergeTwo[i];
            }
            else if(mergeTwo[i]<=mergeOne[i]){
                merged[i] = mergeTwo[i];
                merged[i+1]= mergeOne[i];
            }
        }
        else if(i>0){
            if(mergeOne[i]<=mergeTwo[i]){
                merged[i+i] = mergeOne[i];
                merged[i+i+1] = mergeTwo[i];
            }
            else if(mergeTwo[i]<=mergeOne[i]){
                merged[i+i] = mergeTwo[i];
                merged[i+i+1]= mergeOne[i];
            }
        }
    }
    //If mergeOne.length equals mergeTwo.length, it skips over next step.
    if(mergeOne.length<mergeTwo.length){
        for(int k=lengthShort; k<lengthLong; k++){
            merged[k]=mergeTwo[k];
        }
    }
    //If mergeOne.length equals mergeTwo.length, it skips over next step.
    if(mergeOne.length>mergeTwo.length){
            for(int k=lengthShort; k<lengthLong; k++){
                merged[k]=mergeOne[k];
        }
    }

//STEP D
    //This is supposed to sort the final merged array.
    for(int i = 0; i<merged.length; i++){
        if((i+1)==merged.length)        //Prevents an ErrorOutofBounds message
            break;
        if(merged[i]>merged[i+1]){
            int temp = merged[i+1];
            merged[i+1]=merged[i];
            merged[i]= temp;

        }
    }

    System.out.println("\nMerged array in order is: ");

    for(int i = 0; i<merged.length; i++){
    System.out.print(merged[i] + " ");
    }
}
}
```